# Arduino shuts off randomly (Temperature?)

Tags: arduino-uno, power, temperature

I've got an Arduino Uno running in a case, with a [Fona 808 shield from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-808-cellular-plus-gps-shield-for-arduino?view=all) on top. It's used as a location tracker; it'll get the current GPS location three times a second, then send the average to a webserver.

While testing the Arduino software, I noticed the Arduino would get quite hot and shut off while using a 9V 1A power supply, so instead I opted for powering it through the USB port I also used for debugging. This didn't seem to be a problem, but I haven't tested it for hours at a time.

Right now I've got it installed in my motorcycle. As I felt the 12V would be a bit too much (although it's in the acceptable range) because it couldn't handle 9V, I put a transformer with short-circuit protection in the line, stepping it down to 5V 600mA.

Because this too was cutting out at seemingly random times (3, 2.5, 13 hours), I'm really not sure what to do. The motorcycle is outside, so the outside temperature may interfere with this amazing scientific test, but I don't see any reason for it to get so hot it would turn off completely.

Does anyone have an explanation for it?

Comment: What specifically happens? Does the whole board lose power (no power led on the UNO)? Does the program no longer appear to run? Try adding a blinking led to your code, sort of like a heartbeat, so you can see if the code is still running. If it's the code that locks up, you might want to look into the watchdog timer inside the UNO. Using this watchdog you can make the Arduino reset itself if it stop/hangs.

Comment: That "transformer"?  These do not work between DC sources, so presumably you mean some sort of DC-DC convert.  What you are doing to accomodate the GSM module's notoriously high pulse power demand during transmit??  How much thought have you put into the power consumption savings you will need to achieve to have this run for any substantial period of time on battery?  And how are you juggling two presumably serial peripherals?

Comment: @Gerben I modified the code a bit to make one of the LEDs blink. Can't look at the arduino power LED because it's in a closed case. I'll update as soon as it stops again.